# GeoServer and Hadoop

Tags: raster, geoserver, hadoop-distributed-file-system

I'm working on a GIS application that requires to work with Big Data technologies on a cluster (Cloudera CDH 6.2.0). One node will host a GeoServer instance to provide maps to a web application (built with OpenLayers).
My problem is how to provide rasters (GeoTIFF format) to GeoServer. I have two main solutions for the storage:

- Keep raw raster files on hdfs,
- Yse a tool (HBase?Accumulo?) to save raster data in some way.

Which one is the best?

Once this decision is made, the second point is how to connect GeoServer to data. I need to build layers to provide maps to the webapp but i don't want to store rasters on the local filesystem of the cluster node where GeoServer runs. I want to keep raw data only on HDFS or another store.

Is that solution possible? Is it a good architectural choice? What is a good way to connect GeoServer to HDFS/HBase/other datastore?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We are not a discussion forum, so questions which are highly subjective, like "Which one is the best?" are likely to generate close votes due to being *opinion-based*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of [LocationTech](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/locationtech) Projects which adress this, I think the most mature one is GeoMesa, but also GeoWave is able to store raster data in an distributed key/value (accumolo is mentioned most often here) store and connect it to geoserver.

preferring the **Big Spatial Store Option:** I think you should have a look at [Geomesa Raster tutorial](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-raster.html)

This opens up your raster data for high througput processing engines like RasterFames and GeoTrellis which leverage Spark in general, and therefore allows you to run analytic pipelines on most of your data simultanously.

Pro **Raw HDFS Option:** As long as you don't need any highly sophisticated tiling/processing and (space filling curve) indexing mechanism on the raster data (you just want to show it as a background basemap) it is also possible to just use the files raw from hdfs. As Geoserver uses GDAL and GDAL is able to read also from distributed file stores through its [Virtual File Systems Driver](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html) you just have to define your datasource by providing an corresponding /vsihdfs/-Path to it, but I am afraid you need a special build of the GDAL java binding libraries with HDFS Support set to 'yes'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to install GeoMesa but I faced some compatibility problem with my cluster's services. About the second option you suggested how could a non-standard GDAL build help me in connecting GeoServer with the cluster?